# c# geckofx reference error

Tags: c#, winforms, geckofx

I am trying to load GeckoFX into my app but the following error appears:

"The type or namespace name 'Gecko' could not be found"

And the line is 151: Which is "private Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser geckoWebBrowser1;"

In my references there are items listed as "Geckofx-Core" & "Geckofx-Winforms"

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: did you copied all the geck binaries in Debug folder.?

Comment: You may need to add a "using Gecko" directive to the top of the file.

Comment: @TehCorwiz - +1, but that should be an answer, not a comment...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a "using Gecko" directive to the top of the file.